# Make TinyMCE follow anchors within textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to find a method of making TinyMCE follow anchor links within the textarea. I am trying to make a table of contents, and would like the ability for users to skip the the desired section in the editor. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write an own plugin for that setting the cursor position using methods from the [tinymce class Selection](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#class_tinymce.dom.Selection.html). The newest tinymce version contains the method `setCursorLocation` which may be used for example.